# UITableViewCell imageView not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, afnetworking

So I had the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FriendsCell";

    FriendData * fd = [self.friendsDataSource_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    [cell.imageView  setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fd.imageUrl_]];
    [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [cell.textLabel setText:fd.name_];

    return cell;
}
```

However, I am not seeing the imageView in the cell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: let's see your -setImageWithURL method

Comment: Along with seeing `setImageWithURL:`, are you sure that **`fd.imageUrl_`** is not nil?

Comment: yes the url is valid and is not nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Set Image with URL is not an iOS method. It's something custom and that may be the problem. But until you publish it can't help there.

2) I think cell.imageView will ignore "setFrame". I can't get that to work in any of my table cells using an image. It always seems to default to width of the image.

3) Typically you set the image using cell.imageView.image = your_Image. The ImageView is READONLY and probably the ImageView frame is private.

4) I think you are going to need to create a custom cell of your own.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem with SDImageCache as well. My solution is to put a placeholder image with the frame size you want.

```
 UIImage *placeholder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image.png"];
 [cell.imageView setImage:placeholder];
 [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fd.imageUrl_]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Usage of a method with placeholder will fix it.

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fd.imageUrl_]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to `return cell` at the end of the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FriendsCell";

    FriendData * fd = [self.friendsDataSource_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    [cell.imageView  setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fd.imageUrl_]];
    [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [cell.textLabel setText:fd.name_];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I did that actually.. I just cut it off